# Bright Bike DIY Kits

Tags: visibility, night-riding

I've seen Bright Bike DIY kits suggested as a great way to make yourself visible at night - does anyone know where these can be bought in the UK?  Any suggestions welcomed!

Thanks

Comment: You can find alternative reflective tapes like this [reflective tape](https://m.uline.com/h5/r/www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-15789/Vinyl-Safety-Reflective-Tapes/Reflective-Tape-1-x-10-yds-White) from uline.

Comment: Lightweights already makes a plethora of products like this, available online and elsewhere. Some bike shops in the us carry them. http://lightweights.com/

Comment: Try Life Paint by Volvo. Should be able to make things reflective without affecting the daytime colour too much.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @MrsB. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're asking see [ask] also.

Comment: This question seems suspiciously like an ad in disguise.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions! Definitely not an advert in disguise - not sure how you came to that conclusion RoboKaren!

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an [active Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/mandiberg/bright-bike-diy-kits-night-visibility-for-safer-r).  However, from the Kickstarter page, it seems that the kit is nothing more than lengths of 3M Scotchlite tape. Just buy the tape: it's easily available from Amazon and, I'm sure, from many other places.